# Dashboard shows 79 Succeeded jobs but where is the list?

Tags: hangfire

When I select the "Succeeded" menu in the dashboard, I only show a single job, yet there is a number beside the text "Succeeded" indicating the number of jobs that have executed without error.  How do I see those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hangfire automatically clears jobs after a certain amount of time (usually 1 day by default)

The number beside the succeeded is the total number of successful jobs since the beginning.

See [this answer](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34/2?u=odinserj) from the Hangfire forum